# Name attribute in form tag is not properly working in firefox for jquery

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, google-chrome

This is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(myForm.elements).hide();
}
```

This is how form looks in html :

```
<form name="myForm"></form>
```

Running this in Firefox , will throw an error : `myForm is not defined`

But, this code will run successfully in Chrome and Opera. How to resolve this error in Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `document.forms[0]` instead but if you have several forms on your page that might not be the best solution.

I would use a selector instead of an object

```
$('form[name="myForm"] :input')
```

or

```
$('#myForm :input');

<form id="myForm">
```

The [:input selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) "Selects all input, textarea, select and button elements."

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 `myForm.elements`
```

with

```
 `document.forms[0].elements`
```

now it will work in all the browsers. Note, here this is my first form , So I am having my index as 0, replace it with the appropriate number .

Comment: wow, is this a tutorial about how a question should be answered?

Comment: Thank u @Raminson and Bhuvan_rikka